# Como copiar texto de labels al portapapeles. C# con menu contextual

Tags: c#, label

Tengo 10 labels y mi idea es tener un solo menú contextual, asignado a cada uno de los label, para que copie el texto de cada uno de los label. Me funcionó haciendo un menú para cada label por separado el código de mi menú es el siguiente:

```
private void CopiarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetText(label1.Text);
}
```

pero ahora para usar solamente un solo menú no se como detectar cual label es en el que se esta haciendo clic derecho:

```
Clipboard.SetText(¿...?.Text);
```

Comment: Hola, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void CopiarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                      
   ToolStripItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripItem;

   if (menuItem != null) 
   { 
      ContextMenuStrip owner = menuItem.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;

      if (owner != null) 
      {  
         Control sourceControl = owner.SourceControl;
         Clipboard.SetText(((Label)sourceControl).Text);
      }               
   }            
}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es determinar cual es el control sobre el que se mostró el menú contextual. Para ello cogemos el **parámetro sender** de tipo **object** y lo casteamos a **ToolStripItem**, que vendría siendo el item del menú sobre el que se clicó, posteriormente obtenemos el control dueño al que pertenece este **toolStripItem**, que no es más que el propio control **ContextMenuStrip**, este componente dueño será almacenado en la **variable owner**. Luego verificamos que **owner** no sea **nulo**, de no ser **nulo** pues guardamos el control al que esté asociado este menú que en este caso sería un **Label** y entonces pondríamos el código que te interesa:

```
Clipboard.SetText(((Label)sourceControl).Text);
```

Como sabemos que es un **Label** pues casteamos **sourceControl** a un **Label** y obtenemos el texto de este control casteado que sería ya un **Label**.

```
((Label)sourceControl).Text
```

Comment: Si de hecho eso lo hize en el evento click: llame al metodo y le pase el label al que se de click, puse una llamada por cada label.
pero mi idea es que solo coloque el codigo en el evento del "ContextMenu" y que al dar clic derecho y aparezca el menu (que ya lo hace) aparezca la opcion de copiar (que tambien ya lo hace), y al dar clic en copiar copie el texto del label que se esta dando clic derecho.

Comment: Una pregunta, tu añadiste 10 contextmenu a tu proyecto?

Comment: NO, un solo menu, asignada a todos los label......... en un principio si tenia un menu para cada uno, pero la idea es usar un mismo menu, y aprobecharlo........

Comment: TU respuesta me fue muy útil.
Ya he agregado tu aportación y funciona a la perfección, tal y como lo necesitaba. MUCHAS GRACIAS!!!

Comment: @yahir58, si la respuesta te resultó útil podrías marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto positivo, gracias